# Leveraging multithreading/multiprocessing to insert data into database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, singlestore

I have a series of flat files that need to be inserted into a database, currently I have a looping python script that will read in and execute file by file. This is painstakingly slow as I have ~5000k+ files and ~1B records. How can the below be executed utilizing multithreading or multiprocessing?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import personal_functions as fns

# establish parameters
table_name = 'sql_table_name'
contents = os.listdir(dir_of_files)
contents.sort()

# loop through each file and insert into db
for file in contents:
    temp = pd.read_csv(dir_of_files + file)
    fns.special_insert_function(temp, table_name)
```

Comment: Here's an example right in the docs: [Concurrent Multi-Insert Examples](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.3/en/developer-resources/concurrent-multi-insert-examples/python.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of your files it could be much faster to ingest files from disk using the LOAD DATA command than using INSERT statements: https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/load-data.html